# What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is my Javascript code I have so far.  I am trying to create a personInfo() object with 2 functions. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
var personInfo = 
{
    personInfo.personRelation: " ",
    personInfo.personName: " ",
    personInfo.personAge: 0,
    personInfo.personGender: " "

    var relationValue = personRelation;
    var nameValue = personName; 
    var ageValue = personAge;
    var genderValue = personGender; 

    getPersonInfo: function()               
            {
                document.write( "<p>" + personInfo.personRelation + "<br />" );
                document.write( "Name: " + personInfo.personName + "<br />");
                document.write( "Age: " + personInfo.personAge + "<br />" );
                document.write( "Gender: " + personInfo.personGender + "</p>" );
            }
    setPersonInfo(relationValue, nameValue, ageValue, genderValue): function()
            {
                this.relationValue = relationValue;
                this.nameValue = nameValue;
                this.ageValue = ageValue;
                this.genderValue = genderValue;
            }

}; // end object personInfo
```

This my html code...I am trying to print each object with the while loop.  I am very new to Javascript, so I am not sure if I mistakes in the external javascript file or if it is simply my implementation.  Any help would be great.  Thank you.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="object.css" type ="text/css" />

        <title>Object Test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="MyObject.js">
            var people = new Array(5);
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="MyObject.js">
            var dad_info = setPersonInfo("Dad", "Kenneth Vavrock", 66, "Male");
            dad_info = people[0];
            var mom_info = setPersonInfo("Mom", "Connie Vavrock", 63, "Female");
            mom_info = people[1];
            var brother_info = setPersonInfo("Brother", "Craig Vavrock", 33, "Male");
            brother_info = people[2];
            var nephew_info = setPersonInfo("Nephew", "Sawyer Vavrock", 1, "Male");
            nephew_info = people[3];
            var dad_info = setPersonInfo("Step Mother", "Bonnie Vavrock", 70, "Female");
            stepmother_info = people[4];

            var count = 1;
            while ( count >= 0 )
                {
                    dad_info.getPersonInfo();
                    mom_info.getPersonInfo();
                    brother_info.getPersonInfo();
                    nephew_info.getPersonInfo();
                    stepmother_info.getPersonInfo();
                    count--;
                }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You could start by reading your JS error console: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .`

Comment: `personInfo.personRelation` is not valid as an unquoted key on `personInfo`. It should just be `personRelation`. `var` is not valid inside an object literal; all of those should be removed entirey. `setPersonInfo(relationValue, nameValue, ageValue, genderValue): function()` should be `setPersonInfo: function(relationValue, nameValue, ageValue, genderValue)`. `setPersonInfo` is a property of `personInfo`, so you need to call it as `personInfo.setPersonInfo()`, although that won’t quite work, since you’re trying to use it as a constructor.

Comment: You really need to learn the difference between a code [block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block) and an [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Object_literals).

Comment: Please see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new.

Comment: You've made at least 6 different *kinds* of errors in that code. You need to step back and start small. Deal with getting the code to do one thing at a time (from scratch). Use the debugging tools built into your browser. The question is far too broad as it stands.

Comment: I second the people above. Touch up on JavaScript basics; and learn to use the JavaScript console.

Comment: Thank you all for the tips.. I had a feeling I was digging in too deeply, too quickly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your "personInfo" object is malformed, it looks like a mix between a `object literal` and a class-like `function`.  Have a look at [this](http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/) tutorial

Also, do not use an empty string `" "` as default value for anything (unless you really need to), there is really no point to it.

To solve the problem at hand.

```
var personInfo = function () {
    this.personRelation = "";
    this.personName = "";
    this.personAge = 0;
    this.personGender = "";

    this.getPersonInfo = function () {
        document.write( "<p>" + personInfo.personRelation + "<br />" );
        document.write( "Name: " + personInfo.personName + "<br />");
        document.write( "Age: " + personInfo.personAge + "<br />" );
        document.write( "Gender: " + personInfo.personGender + "</p>" );
    }

};
```

This way it can be used as such:

```
var people = []; // Create an empty array

// Create new person info for "dad"
var dad_info = new personInfo();
dad_info.personRelation = "...";
// [...]

people.push(dad_info); // Add dad_info to the array.
```

You should be all set.